# Difference between loading javascript file via async=false and script tag without async attribute

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, tags, synchronous

**First Way:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

**Second Way:**

```
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "jquery.js";
js.async = false;//THIS ATTRIBUTE

var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
h.parentNode.appendChild(js);
```

Question: What is the difference between above two ways. **Google Page Speed Insight** Tool doesn't complain about `First Way` as `Render blocking issue`.

FYI: We have to load `jQuery` file without `async` because `GTM` is dependent upon it.

Comment: Where and how are you running the "Second Way" above?

Comment: *"FYI: We have to load `jQuery` file without async because `GTM` is dependent upon it."* All that means is that you need to load GTM after jQuery. It *doesn't* mean you have to load jQuery synchronously.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I run it in place of `First Way` at the top of page and before `GTM`. And GTM is loaded `async`. So, `jQuery` can't be `async` as well.

Comment: In a `<script>...</script>` block? In a `<script src="..."></script>` block? Any flags on the latter, if so?

Comment: ohh, I do it in `<script>....</script>` and directly in the `head` tag itself.

Comment: Why can't you just load both scripts in the normal way?

Comment: `GTM` recommends it to load `async` and to load any other depending files before it either `inline` or `without async`.

Comment: What is this "GTM"? In any case, it sounds like they're just saying to do this: `<script src="jquery.js"></script><script src="gtm.js" async></script>`. (If so, don't do it in `head`; do it at the end of `body`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151015/discussion-between-imatoria-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: I don't do the chat thing when it's relevant to clarifying the question. I believe clarification comments belong on the question.

Comment: `GTM` is `Google Tag Manager`. Its not just `Google Tag Manager` that I have to load but also `Google Optimize` and `Google Analytics` for `Google Experiments`. And they all load async.

Comment: That's fine. There's no reason you can't have multiple `<script src="..." async></script>` tags. Which is almost certainly what Google means; if you look deeper in the documentation, you should find actual examples.

Answer (score 2):

The [WHAT-WG HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) goes into **great detail** about how scripts are loaded.

The fundamental difference — try not to laugh — is that the one is part of the HTML and the other is generated by JavaScript code.

With the `script` tag in the HTML:

- The browser can discover and begin downloading (but not executing) the script in parallel with the DOM builder until the DOM builder reaches that point in the token stream
- The script is also allowed to use `document.write` without blowing away the document
- The main JavaScript UI thread isn't held up until the script is actually executed

When you add the `script` element with JavaScript code with `async = false`:

- The browser can't pre-download it
- The script can't use `document.write` without blowing away the document
- The main JavaScript UI thread is blocked waiting for the download, not just when the script is executing

While it's true that `<script src="..."></script>` without the `async` or `defer` attribute (e.g., a blocking script tag) blocks page load, the impact can be less severe.

That said, I'd be **very** surprised if PageSpeed doesn't complain about a blocking script tag in the `head`. Without **very** good reason to do something else, blocking `script` tags should be at the end of `body`, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

From the comments, it seems you're using Google scripts, and you've said they want the `script` tags in `head`. They probably mean for you to use `defer` (to preserve order between the scripts):

```
<script src="jquery.js" defer></script>
<script src="gtm.js" defer></script>
```

...in `head`. `defer` means that the scripts *don't* hold up the DOM (they download in parallel but don't run until DOM parsing is complete), but *do* execute in order.

Comment: As per new guidelines by `Google`, its script should load `async` and at the top of `head` tag to avoid any page tracking miss. Also, I using `Google Experiments` so I have to load it as early as possible to avoid `FLASH` of document.

Comment: @iMatoria: (Please don't mark up non-code as `code`, it impairs readability.) Perhaps you could refer us to the doc in question. I would expect them to suggest `defer`, not `async`, if there's dependency between the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

For 1st method : There are several ways an external script can be executed.

- If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the
  rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page
  continues the parsing)
- If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed
  when the page has finished parsing
- If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and
  executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page

For 2nd method

- async:false = Code paused. (Other code waiting for this to finish.)
- async:true = Code continued. (Nothing gets paused. Other code is not
  waiting.)

Comment: Yea, we know it. But, question is in relation to `script` tag.

Comment: I doubt that is entirely correct because `Google Page Speed Insight` doesn't complain about the `Second way` for `Render blocking script`. I believe `Second way` doesn't completely block the thread.